# `na.string = na.strings=c('',' ')` in R introduces a new and unwanted factor level NA

Tags: r, data.table

I have etroubles removing some `NA` from a `data.table`. I imported the datast using the following command, where all empty cells have been replaced with `NA`. I noticed that the `na.strings=c('',' ')` actually creates a new level.

**How can this be avoided?** I guess it has something to do with the format of the variable

```
mydata<- setDT(read.csv("~/mydata.csv",na.strings=c('',' ') ))
> str(mydata[,10:11])
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  295114 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ location: Factor w/ 22 levels "BALI","BANTEN",..: 4 4 4 4 4 4 6 6 6 6 ...
 $ region  : Factor w/ 6 levels "Eastern Indonesia",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 ...
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 
> summary(mydata[,10:11])
             location                    region      
 DKI JAKARTA     :2263   Eastern Indonesia:  14  
 BANTEN          : 356   Jakarta          :2263  
 JAWA BARAT      : 150   Java&Bali        : 637  
 JAWA TIMUR      : 128   Kalimantan       :  15  
 KALIMANTAN TIMUR:  15   NA               :  17  
 (Other)         :  18   Sumatra          :   2  
 NA's            :  17  



      mydata<- setDT(read.csv("~/mydata.csv",na.strings=' '))
 > str(clientData[,10:11])
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  295114 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ location: Factor w/ 23 levels "","BALI","BANTEN",..: 5 5 5 5 5 5 7 7 7 7 ...
 $ region  : Factor w/ 6 levels "Eastern Indonesia",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 ...
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 
> summary(clientData[,10:11])
             location                    region      
 DKI JAKARTA     :22635   Eastern Indonesia:  147  
 BANTEN          : 3568   Jakarta          :22635  
 JAWA BARAT      : 1507   Java&Bali        : 6379  
 JAWA TIMUR      : 1289   Kalimantan       :  155  
                 :  171   NA               :  171  
 KALIMANTAN TIMUR:  154   Sumatra          :   22
```

i tried to remove these `NA` manually

```
mydata <- mydata[!region == 'NA', ] 

> summary(mydata[,11])
               countries      
 Eastern Indonesia:  1472  
 Jakarta          :226357  
 Java&Bali        : 63791  
 Kalimantan       :  1557  
 NA               :  0  
 Sumatra          :   222
```

How can i remove the entire level `NA` from my data?

Could that be written as a function that check all columns of `mydata` which are factors and if there is a level `NA` remove it ? something like

```
clean_data <- function(data){
  # if columns is factor - drop levels "NA"
  # otherwise remove NAs 
}
```

or

```
mydata <- lapply(mydata, function(x) if(is.factor(x)) droplevels(x) else x)
```

Comment: Do you want columns of type `factor` ? You could use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in `read.csv` to keep them in character.

Comment: @RonakShah, yes i do want columns of type factor

Comment: Can you add data using `dput` ? `dput(head(mydata))` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we have `NA` as levels in the dataframe, we can remove it by converting values to factors again. Since `factor` by default excludes `NA` while generating factor levels.

```
df1[] <- lapply(df1, function(x) if(is.factor(x)) factor(x) else x)
```

Using `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% mutate_if(is.factor, factor)
```

---

Consider this example,

```
x <- factor(c(NA, 'a', 'b'), exclude = NULL)
df1 <- data.frame(a = x, b = x)

str(df1)
#'data.frame':  3 obs. of  2 variables:
# $ a: Factor w/ 3 levels "a","b",NA: 3 1 2
# $ b: Factor w/ 3 levels "a","b",NA: 3 1 2

df1[] <- lapply(df1, function(x) if(is.factor(x)) factor(x) else x)
str(df1)
#'data.frame':  3 obs. of  2 variables:
# $ a: Factor w/ 2 levels "a","b": NA 1 2
# $ b: Factor w/ 2 levels "a","b": NA 1 2
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use an index method

```
i1 <- sapply(df1, is.factor)
df[i1] <- lapply(df1, factor)
```